# Performance of array_merge vs union in PHP

Tags: php, performance, memory, cpu, internals

I am trying to understand how **`array_merge`** and **`union`** work behind the scenes in PHP out of curiosity.

Can someone help me to understand the ZEND internals behind the scenes of:

- **`array_merge`** (slower on CPU and RAM)
- **`UNION`** (faster in all aspects)

Here is the benchmark code I am running: https://gist.github.com/EnchanterIO/6e90f828c1b32c894d35267c353e83d2

The output using PHP 7 is:

> ➜  ArrayMerge git:(master) ✗ php src/benchmark.php array_merge 20000
>
> Building array of 20000 elements using array_merge took 7 seconds.
>
> Memory usage is: 8 MB. Memory peak was: 12288 MB.
>
> ➜  ArrayMerge git:(master) ✗ php src/benchmark.php union 20000
>
> Building array of 20000 elements using union took 0 seconds.
>
> Memory usage is: 8 MB. Memory peak was: 10240 MB.

**My theory for array_merge:**

I am looking at the [PHP source code written in C for array merge](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L3714) (if this is even the right place) and even though it's a bit unreadable to me, as I am not familiar with the jargon, it seems like the reason why `array_merge` is slower is due to the extra foreach required and also due to the fact that `array_merge` renumbers numeric keys in the resulting array.

**My theory for UNION:**

Didn't find a source code for it but as far I know adding elements to the array works like this:

- at the beginning an array has some amount of memory allocated internally
- by adding new elements to the array, eventually the array needs to have more memory assigned dynamically in the background so PHP internals (C) creates a new array with double the amount of the memory and copies the content
- by adding even more elements this process repeats
- no reordering, no foreach, just increasing the memory over time

Can anyone shed more light on the process and explain the behind the scenes ZEND magic in-depth?

**Update:**

I was referred to the following links but still can't get my head around it:

https://lxr.room11.org/xref/php-src%40master/Zend/zend_opcode.c#740
https://lxr.room11.org/xref/php-src%40master/Zend/zend_operators.c#897
https://lxr.room11.org/xref/php-src%40master/Zend/zend_hash.c#1915

Comment: The two codes you're comparing don't do the same thing. In particular, should `$list[] = [$i => [$i]]` be `$list[$i] = [$i]` or `$list[] = [$i]` instead?

Comment: and where in your benchmark code did you apply array union?

Comment: @NikiC ah... you are right!!! I was so focused on the PHP internals and I somehow overlooked this bug. That explains the double memory required as I was creating an array with too high index ($i) instead of with 0 index! Okay, the memory bug is fixed. Now it makes sense. And my theory for UNION is correct? Would u add some additional explanation to the array merge part? I added some ZEND links that could be helpful. Revo how would you call: "list[$i] = [$i]" ?

Comment: @EnchanterIO The pertinent difference between array_merge and []= here is that array_merge copies the array and []= doesn't (unless a capacity increase is necessary). That's why array_merge is O(n) and []= is (amortized) O(1). Run in a loop, that's the difference between O(n^2) and O(n). The specific implementation details stop mattering at that point.

Comment: actually after further examination I realised my previous benchmark is misleading and hardly used in some real life scenario @NikiC. Check my answer with more details and second benchmark Niki please.

Answer (score 1):

I believe my benchmark was unfair because (hopefully no one with common sense) would loop through an array and then use **array_merge** to merge **one** element.

I crated a new [benchmark](https://gist.github.com/EnchanterIO/51afd5c816a764daf866227ce84a07b2) showing the difference between merging 2 big arrays into one using **foreach and manual addition** and using **array_merge**.

[image]

**Result**

There is no performance advantage of merging two arrays **manually** comparing to merging them with **array_merge**.